# Does anyone implemeted Isosurface Stuffing algorithm using c++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, mesh

I wanted to develop the code of IS algorithm but I was wondering to know is c++ language will be a better choice to implement or any other language do I need to look out?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes.  Its been done.  https://github.com/crawforddoran/quartet